# How to set an instance variable in subclass even though it's private and declared in superclass?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass, imageicon

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class City {
private String name;
private int population, x, y;
private ImageIcon marker;

public City(String name, int population, int x, int y) {
    marker = new ImageIcon("marker_city.png");
    this.name = name;
    this.population = population;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public ImageIcon getMarker() {
    return marker;
}

public void setMarker(ImageIcon marker) {
    this.marker = marker;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
}
```

I need to create a subclass with a different ImageIcon file ("marker_prov.png"). How should I set the `marker` variable? This one has to remain private in the superclass.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ProvCapital extends City {
private String province;

public ProvCapital(String name, int population, int x, int y, String province) {
    super(name, population, x, y, marker);
    marker = new ImageIcon("marker_prov.png");
    this.province = province;
}
```

I think I can use the getter or setter since they are public but I don't know how.

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to use the setter? Just try it

Comment: Why don't you make `marker` `protected`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changing the constructor of class `ProvCapital`. Drop the `marker` parameter, since you ignore it anyway. Try the following constructor.

```java
public ProvCapital(String name, int population, int x, int y, String province) {
    super(name, population, x, y, new ImageIcon("marker_prov.png"));
    this.province = province;
}
```

### EDIT

Actually, I see that you also ignore the `marker` parameter in the constructor of class `City`, so may as well drop that, too. Just keep the `setMarker()` method. Try the following constructor for class `City`

```java
public City(String name, int population, int x, int y) {
    setMarker(new ImageIcon("marker_city.png"));
    this.name = name;
    this.population = population;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Then change the constructor for class `ProvCapital` as follows.

```java
public ProvCapital(String name, int population, int x, int y, String province) {
    super(name, population, x, y);
    setMarker(new ImageIcon("marker_prov.png"));
    this.province = province;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I noticed that I ignore the `marker` in both classes. I changed it accordingly. I found the setter in subclass should work, but can I keep the way in the superclass. I mean still have `marker = new ImageIcon("marker_city.png");` in the constructor and declare `setMarker` later in the superclass?

Answer (score 0):

```
marker = new ImageIcon("marker_prov.png");
setMarker(marker);
```

Should do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new (protected) constructor in `City` that takes the `marker` as parameter:

```
protected City(String name, int population, int x, int y, ImageIcon marker) {
    this.name = name;
    this.population = population;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.marker = marker;
}
```

ideally, reuse it in the public constructor:

```
public City(String name, int population, int x, int y) {
    this(name, popoulation, x, y, new ImageIcon("marker_city.png"));
}
```

then pass the chosen marker in the `super()` call from the subclass:

```
public ProvCapital(String name, int population, int x, int y, String province) {
    super(name, population, x, y, new ImageIcon("marker_prov.png"));
    this.province = province;
}
```

This approach even allows you to remove the setter and make the `marker` final, if desired.